# Issue with if/else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, for-else

I'm fairly new to coding and I've come across a problem I can't figure out or find an answer to.

Basically everytime the user enters yes into the raw_input it spits out the 'if' string but then doesnt exclude the 'else' string.

I'm assuming its because the delay is interfering and I havent set it out correctly because in the code it goes (If, For,  Else), maybe the For is hindering the code, I don't know. Would appreciate some help! :)

```
import sys
import time
string = 'Hello comrade, Welcome!\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.03)
time.sleep(1)
x=raw_input('Are you ready to enter the fascinating Mists of Verocia? ')
if x == 'yes':
   string = "Verocia was a mystical land located just south of Aborne"
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.03)
else:
    print ('Please restart program whenever you are ready!')
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, as it's currently written the `if` has no `else` - the `else` belongs to the `for` loop and is executed as long as no `break` is used inside of the loop.

Comment: Python is indent-sensitive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please mind the indentation. I think the for loop should be inside the if statement.

```
if x == 'yes':
    string = "Verocia was a mystical land located just south of Aborne"
    for char in string:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(.03)
else:
    print ('Please restart program whenever you are ready!')
```

Comment: Don't use `string` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent the **for** loop. Loops in Python have **else** clause - it is executed when the loop runs through, without **break** issued

Answer (score 0):

Indent the for loop correctly, you will get your result.

```
import sys
import time
strWelcome = 'Hello comrade, Welcome!\n'
for char in strWelcome :
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.03)
time.sleep(1)
x=raw_input('Are you ready to enter the fascinating Mists of Verocia? ')
if x == 'yes':
   str1 = "Verocia was a mystical land located just south of Aborne"
    for char in str1:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(.03)
else:
    print ('Please restart program whenever you are ready!')
```

Comment: Don't use `string` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

There is an indentation problem in your code. It should be:

```
import sys
import time
string = 'Hello comrade, Welcome!\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.03)
time.sleep(1)
x=raw_input('Are you ready to enter the fascinating Mists of Verocia? ')
if x == 'yes':
   string = "Verocia was a mystical land located just south of Aborne"
   for char in string:
     sys.stdout.write(char)
     sys.stdout.flush()
     time.sleep(.03)
else:
    print ('Please restart program whenever you are ready!')
```

Answer (score 0):

in your example, the else condition is connected to the for statement.
The else suite is executed after the for, but only if the for terminates normally (not by a break).